# is there a way to change the saturation value by using a light?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

My scene's background is too bright and too saturated compared to my foreground.

To lower the brightness, I used a lamp with a negative value, which made my background darker. But is there a similar solution to lower the saturation or the contrast?

How do you manage globally the colors/saturation/etc. of big parts of a scene?

Thanks!

Comment: i would search for the reason of your bright background, and reduce that. But since we have nearly no information about your setup - we can just guess. Maybe turn down the strength of your background node in your world shader? If you wanna have a precise answer, pls upload your blend file. thank you.

Comment: @Chris sorry for being so vague, but my question is very generic. Is there a way to reduce locally the saturation of a set without changing the shader one by one, in the same way that you can reduce the light with a lamp with a negative value?

Comment: my problem is also to have the saturation reduced uniformly

Comment: Hi Pyra, i also just know the trick with the negative value of a lamp, sorry.

Comment: Please flesh this question out a bit. Is your background an HDR ( World) .. or lit components of your scene?

Comment: @RobinBetts it is lit components